# Property 'style' does not exist on type 'CSSProperties'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm changing a component from jsx to tsx and I'm having a typescript problem with a component that is using MaterialUI Grid. This is the code:

```
const GridItem = ({ style }: React.CSSProperties) => (
    <Grid item style={{ ...{ textAlign: 'center', marginBottom: 0 }, ...style }}>
    {children}
    </Grid>
    )
```

I'm receiving this error:
[image]

> Property 'style' does not exist on type 'CSSProperties'.ts(2339)

I have tried changing from CSSProperties to Element but I get the same error menssage. And HTMLCollectionOf as well..

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `CSSProperties`, `Element` and `HTMLCollection` are all very different types of things. What do you actually *want*? How do you plan to call/use the `<GridItem>`?

Comment: You probably meant to write `({ style }: { style: React.CSSProperties; }) => …`. Or possibly use an `interface GridItemProps { style: React.CSSProperties; }`

Comment: React.CSSProperties does not have property style it is the style, try removing curly brackets

Comment: thanks @Bergi using a interface works. Post the answer so I can choose yours.